# How to change Bitmap1 for ToolBarToolBase Object in wxPython

Tags: python, wxpython, toolbar

How does one change the "image" shown on a toolbar button dynamically in wxPython?

```
frame = wx.Frame( ... )
tb = frame.CreateToolBar()
tool_bmp = wx.Bitmap("/path/to/tool.png", wx.BITMAP_TYPE_PNG)
tb.AddLabelTool(id=wx.ID_ANY, label="Clicky", bitmap=tool_bmp, bmpDisabled=wx.NullBitmap, shortHelp="Clicky")
tbtb = tb.GetToolByPos(0)
```

Specifically, I want to change the "image" shown on the ToolBarToolBase object `tbtb`. I have tried things like:

```
new_bmp = wx.Bitmap("/path/to/new.png", wx.BITMAP_TYPE_PNG)
tbtb.SetBitmap1(new_bmp)
tb.Refresh()
```

and

```
tool_bmp = wx.BitMap("/path/to/new.png, sx.BITMAP_TYPE_PNG)
tb.Refresh()
```

to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [SetNormalBitmap](http://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/ToolBarToolBase.html#ToolBarToolBase.SetNormalBitmap) instead

```
new_bmp = wx.Bitmap("/path/to/new.png", wx.BITMAP_TYPE_PNG)
tbtb.SetNormalBitmap(new_bmp)
tb.Realize()
tb.Refresh()
```